# Disable scrolling in SlickGrid

Tags: slickgrid

This may sound crazy, but I'd like to prevent scrolling in SlickGrid.  I'd like to always show all of the data, regardless of how many rows it is.  Is this possible with SlickGrid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

Set the autoHeight property of the grid to true. This will have the effect of making the grid as tall as necessary to contain all rows without requiring scrolling.

Comment: Can't believe that I missed that property.  Thanks for pointing it out to me.

Comment: I have a case where this is not working.   I have several slickgrids on a page.  depending on what order you open them (make visible), the one on the top will sometimes show scrollbars.  I do have that property set and if you open the grids on the top it works fine.